# Does Playwright Test support globalThis? (typescript/javascript)

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright

1. I defined in `global.d.ts` file as the following

```
declare global {
  var some: string
}
```

2. I assigned the value in `global.setup.ts` as the following

```
globalThis.some = 'fff'
```

3. I referred it in test file as the following

```
console.log(globalThis.some)
```

And I did not see `fff` in console log, and neither it reports any error.

Any clue?

expecting seeing `fff` in console log.

Comment: Is `global.setup.ts` being run

Comment: @kelsny yes. It ran.